# Dynamic update of class attributes between different classes

Tags: python, oop, properties, attributes

I'm trying to manage a directory tree which is created through a hierarchy of Python objects. I want to serialize the top-level object in JSON so I can share 2 things with users: the JSON file along with the directory. I'd like other users to be able to point to that directory, so the problem here is setting that root directory which might change on a different computer.

Here's an example of what I have right now:

```
import os.path as op
class Top():
    def __init__(self, root_dir):
        self._root_dir = root_dir

        intop = InTop(self.base_dir)
        self.intop = intop

    @property
    def root_dir(self):
        return self._root_dir

    @root_dir.setter
    def root_dir(self, path):
        self._root_dir = path

    @property
    def base_dir(self):
        return op.join(self.root_dir, 'Top')

class InTop():
    def __init__(self, root_dir):
        self._intop_dir = op.join(root_dir, 'InTop')

    @property
    def intop_dir(self):
        return self._intop_dir

    @intop_dir.setter
    def intop_dir(self, path):
        self._intop_dir = path
```

I'm happy with how this works right now for updating the path in a Top object:

```
t = Top('~/projects/')
print(t.root_dir)  # ~/projects/
print(t.base_dir)  # ~/projects/Top

t.root_dir = '~/Downloads/'
print(t.root_dir)  # ~/Downloads/
print(t.base_dir)  # ~/Downloads/Top
```

But is there any way for that change to propagate to the InTop object?

```
t = Top('~/projects/')
print(t.root_dir)  # ~/projects/
print(t.base_dir)  # ~/projects/Top
print(t.intop.intop_dir)  # ~/projects/Top/InTop

t.root_dir = '~/Downloads/'
print(t.root_dir)  # ~/Downloads/
print(t.base_dir)  # ~/Downloads/Top
print(t.intop.intop_dir)  # ~/projects/Top/InTop   <--- How to update this?
```

How do I get that last line to print "~/Downloads/Top/InTop" instead?

Perhaps there is a better way to manage relative file paths like this - if so please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out..just needed to set it within the Top setter (also corrected my setters)

```
import os.path as op
class Top(object):
    def __init__(self, root_dir):
        self._root_dir = root_dir

        intop_obj = InTop(self.top_dir)
        self.intop = intop_obj

    @property
    def root_dir(self):
        return self._root_dir

    @root_dir.setter
    def root_dir(self, path):
        self._root_dir = path
        self.intop.top_dir = self.top_dir

    @property
    def top_dir(self):
        return op.join(self.root_dir, 'Top')

class InTop(object):
    def __init__(self, top_dir):
        self._top_dir = top_dir

    @property
    def top_dir(self):
        return self._top_dir

    @top_dir.setter
    def top_dir(self, top_dir):
        self._top_dir = top_dir

    @property
    def intop_dir(self):
        return op.join(self.top_dir, 'InTop')
```

Gets me:

```
t = Top('~/projects/')
print(t.root_dir)  # ~/projects/
print(t.top_dir)  # ~/projects/Top
print(t.intop.intop_dir)  # ~/projects/Top/InTop

t.root_dir = '~/Downloads/'
print(t.root_dir)  # ~/Downloads/
print(t.top_dir)  # ~/Downloads/Top
print(t.intop.intop_dir)  # ~/Downloads/Top/InTop
```